# Able to Select few record from table with limit but not able to run select * on whole record

Tags: hive, orc

select * with limit is working in hive. But when I am trying to select the whole record it's failing with error:

> Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io. Text cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable

Most of the columns are string type in that record and few columns are of bigint type,

```
col1 string,
col2 string,
col3 bigint,
col4 bigint,
col5 string
```

Comment: create the SQL please ? if youre using UNION,insert /update,, this is a common problem.